# Split time series according to specific months

Tags: r, xts

I am using `xts` package to split the time series in to monthly, yearly, etc. The code I am using is

```
obsm<-split(obs, f = 'months', drop=FALSE, k = 1)
```

where 'obs' being the whole time series with four year data (1999-2012). I can also split the series in to years, quarters, weeks. But is there anyway where I can split the series for the time period I want. for eg every year from September to November?

Comment: So you would like to get a list like this: [[1]] Jan 99 - Sep 99, [[2]] Oct 99 - Nov 99, [[3]] Dec 99 - Sep 00, [[4]] Oct 00 - Nov 00, etc, correct?

Comment: It also serves my purpose. But I would prefer if I can get it like 
[[1]] Sep 99 -Dec 99, [[2]] Sep 00 -Dec 00 and so on. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do: first subset only the months you need, then split them by year. Using dummy data:

```
x <- as.xts(zooreg(1:2000, start = as.Date("2000-01-01")))
split(x[.indexmon(x) %in% 8:11], f="years")
```

The idea with `.indexmon` is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/subset-data-by-month-in-r).